# Where can I get material for learning EBNF?

Tags: compiler-construction, boost, parsing, bnf, ebnf

Extended Backus–Naur Form: **EBNF**

I'm very new to parsing concepts. Where can I get sufficiently easy to read and follow material for writing a grammar for the boost::spirit library, which uses a grammar similar to EBNF?

Currently I am looking into [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article is accurate.  If you have access, definitely read [Wirth's original article](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=359883) on EBNF.

The other thing to know is that EBNF was designed to make it **easy to hand-write recursive-descent parsers** for languages in which each syntactic construct has identifying keywords at the beginning.  Curly braces translate to `while` loops; square brackets (optional stuff) translates to `if`, and alternatives translate to `if-then-else` or `case` statements.  If you have the luxury of designing your language this way you can knock out a parser quickly *and* give good error messages.

The only place this gets a bit tedious is when you have a language in which there are infix operators with many different levels of precedence.  For that you want Dave Hanson's paper [Compact Recursive-Descent Parsing of Expressions](http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/journal/113447083/abstract?CRETRY=1&SRETRY=0).  Maybe the Princeton tech report series has a free version, and you can always look at the code in [Hanson's C front end](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc).

Comment: Do a search for "Compiler Construction Niklaus Wirth", it ought to return a link to where you can freely download the latest version of his excellent book. Or check out his home page http://www.cs.inf.ethz.ch/~wirth/

Answer (score 5):

BNF itself is simple, but you need to get used to the way compiler writers think. They are not necessarily easy read, but following are lecture notes from UC Berkeley and Stanford.

- [Berkeley CS 164: Lecture Notes](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs164/sp08/lectures/index.html)
- [Stanford CS143: Lecture Notes](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs143/materials/lectures/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://karmin.ch/ebnf/index) is an ebnf parser in php.

Also, learning a little about how regular expression engines are implemented might help. Try: [re2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that Wikipedia is the simplest way for two reasons:

- It states the most relevant points on the article
- It has links for further reading at the bottom of the page

Also I would suggest reading of [standart BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) just to get familiar with the idea behind it.

At least I always start with Wikipedia too, and it almost always helps.